# Brand logo making a link

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am successfully using this code to display a brand logo

php $brand=$_product->getAttributeText('brand');

echo '

'_',$brand).'.jpg" alt="'.$brand.'">'

now what i need help with is making it a link as well

the problem is where as

My brands have capital letters as my attribute does  so for example
Brand Punch It Performance
uses image Punch_It_performance.jpg

however the url for it is

/shop-by-brand/punch-it-performance.html

now forgive my newbieness to php here but i could really use some help modifying the above code snippet to function so when its clicked it goes to the proper page

Comment: Wouldnt let me post this code above 
<?php $brand=$_product->getAttributeText('brand');

echo '<img src="/skin/frontend/default/default/images/media/'.str_replace(' ', 

'_',$brand).'.jpg" alt="'.$brand.'">' ?>

</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php
$brand = $_product->getAttributeText('brand');
$brandImage = str_replace(' ', '_', $brand) . ".jpg";
$brandLink = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $brand)) . ".html";
$brandBaseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl() . '/shop-by-brand/';
?>
<a href="<?php echo $brandBaseUrl . $brandLink; ?>" title="<?php echo $brand; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("images/media/" . $brandImage); ?>" alt="<?php echo $brand; ?>" />
</a>
```

Edit1: fixed typo

Comment: getting a syntax error on this line

Comment: $brandLink = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $brand) . ".html";

Comment: I got this working  <?php $brand=$_product->getAttributeText('brand');
echo strtolower('<a href="/'.str_replace(' ', '-',$brand).'.html" alt="'.$brand.'">') ;
echo '<img src="/skin/frontend/default/default/images/media/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$brand).'.jpg" alt="'.$brand.'">' ?></a>

Comment: I updated my answer, that line was missing a character.

Comment: awesome thanks , now say i have another attribute "restrictions" with 2 options Off Road and Race Only  i tried using the same code snippet to display a image named Off_Road.jpg and Race_Only.jpg but it come back blank maybe i didnt set up the new attribute correctly?

Comment: <?php
$restrictions = $_product->getAttributeText('restrictions');
$restrictionsImage = str_replace(' ', '_', $restrictions) . ".jpg";
$restrictionsLink = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $restrictions)) . ".html";
$restrictionsBaseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl() . '/shop-by-brand/';
?>
<a href="<?php echo $brandBaseUrl . $brandLink; ?>" title="<?php echo $restrictions; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("images/media/" . $restrictionsImage); ?>" alt="<?php echo $restrictions; ?>" />
</a>

Comment: Thanks so much Vincent now let me pick your brain one more time :) i want to add a html or maybe text file that has a little info about each brand how can i call this onto the page, or i guess i would be better off adding it into a attribute? Let me know your thoughts thankls

Comment: Wow been a while everything is working wonderful i was able to use these snippets to obtain perfect results, now i got one small issue, i have a product that does not have a brand  what would i need to do  to make it so if there is no product it shows a none.jpg which could be blank thanks for your help